# Delphi Firemonkey MeasureText not working as expected

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have Delphi 10 Seattle Version 23.0.22248.5795.  I am using the following code snipet

```
ARectF := TRectF.Create(0,0,0,0);
ABitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.bkSolid;
ABitmap.Canvas.StrokeThickness := 1;
ABitmap.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Red;
ABitmap.Canvas.Font.Size := 18;
ABitmap.Canvas.Font.Family:='Arial';
ABitmap.Canvas.Font.Style:=[TFontStyle.fsbold];

ABitmap.Canvas.MeasureText(ARectF, Text, False, [], TTextAlign.Leading);
ARectF := TRectF.Create(0, 0, 50, 20);  //<---- needed to show, but not correct width!
ARectF.TranslateTo(BottomLeftPt); 
if ABitmap.Canvas.BeginScene then try
  DrawFilledRect(ABitmap, ARectF, BackgroundColor, BorderColor, 1, TBrushKind.Solid, 0, 0);
  ARectF.Left := ARectF.Left + 2;
  ABitmap.Canvas.FillText(ARectF, Text, False, 100, [], TTextAlign.Leading);
finally
  ABitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```

When I call the MeasureText function, it is not passing back ARectF with the TRectF needed to display the text.  So I have to manually set up ARectF just to see anything.  Notice that I set it to 0, 0, 50, 20.  I want to be able to remove this line, but without it, only a single dot is shown on the screen.

I tried tracing through the Delphi code, and it seems to involve layouts, which I have not been using. I am just recently converting from VCL to FMX, and I am trying to port code.  I haven't yet figured out how layouts work.  And frankly, I just want to draw text on the screen.

The documentation for MeasureText() seems to indicate that ARectF is the output variable.  Am I misunderstanding the purpose of this function?  If so, how should I properly know how wide the text rectangle should be for handling inputs of variable length?

Can anyone help me figure out why MeasureText is not correctly setting up ARectF for me?

Comment: The docs say: "If ARect is not initialized, the returned rectangle is centered in (0,0)." Did you take that into consideration? I haven't tried, but you should probably initialize it with a width <> 0, in which the text will be written (and, if necessary, wrapped). The height is probably adjusted accordingly.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis thank you for your reply.  I don't quite understand what you are saying.  You said to initialize it with a width in which the text will be written.  But I thought the purpose of this was to tell *me* what the width should be.  For example, if I want to write "Hello", that width will be different than if I want to write "Hello World."  As far as the rectangle being centered at 0,0, that is OK, I translate the entire thing to where I want it to be on the screen.  I'm just trying to find out the text width.

Comment: Looks like perhaps I should be using TCanvas.TextWidth(Text);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MeasureText treats the `ARectF` parameter as the rectangle into which the text is to be placed considering the size of the bounding rectangle and text alignments and other settings. The returned `ArectF` contains the actual bounding rectangle into which the text would be rendered.

For example:

Input value of ARectF

```
ARectF := TRectF.Create(0,0,200,100);
```

Other params as in your example

Return value is (rounded by me)

```
Left: 0
Top: 39.7
Right: 44.0
Bottom: 60.3
```

Horizontally at the left because of TTextAlign.Leading.

Vertically at the center because of TTextAlign.Centered

The documentation is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: What you write rings true.  I just wish the documentation could have been more helpful  :-)